# how to remove myself

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I asked one question and got three answers from 2 people over four days showing neither ever read the question or the updates.  One suggested his death.  Not helpful and want nothing more to do with this group.

Answer (score 3):

Your account is scheduled for deletion. If you change your mind, you can comment here and I can stop it.

I think your reaction is a little strong. I took a look at the question, there is only one answer along with a series of comments (comments are not answers). I didn't see a recommendation for euthanasia, it was acknowledgement that symptoms like you mentioned are often associated with terminal illnesses. Maybe an ill-considered attempt at "softening" the potential, but it was not a recommendation.

In any event, your question is well nigh impossible to answer without some ability to physically examine the cat and there's really nobody qualified on the site. There are loads of possibilities, a laundry list of potential causes is not really helpful other than to cause unnecessary worry. Aside from all that, this is a pure volunteer site, we're not paid employees, and so we don't have an obligation to answer.

Comment: As the author of thge comment that is being complained about: yeah, perhaps Ill considered. To me, the wish was first "good luck" and then, if the worst happens, best wishes... But I can certainly see why a stressed pet owner could misread it. Something to keep in mind. (And of course if I had known how it was being interpreted I'd have apologised and removed it.)

Comment: @keshlam - I wouldn't stress too much. I thought you meant well, but you can't win them all when it comes to an impersonal mechanism.

Comment: I think SE's concept of expert answers (or at least answers reviewed by the collective expertise if the community) leads some newcomers to expect that experts are standing by and that only experts will respond. That isn't really what we've got. If you want pet experts on call, a better bet would be to contact your local emergency vet (whoever your vet suggests for after hours coverage) or perhaps your local SPCA if they're good. Admittedly I'm very lucky; MSPCA runs 24-hour walk-in veterinary clinics within reasonable driving distance of my house, plus Angell Memorial vet hospital.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you've had such a tough time on our site. If you want to delete your account, you can use the [Contact Page](https://pets.stackexchange.com/contact) to ask for your account to be deleted.

One thing to note, though, is that content you've posted on the site is owned by you [but licensed to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post), and you therefore cannot request that it be deleted with your account.